# How to resolve flutter_cupertino_localizations package compile error

Tags: flutter

My project uses the flutter_cupertino_localizations package and used to compile and run fine. As of today I am getting below compile error.

```
Compiler message:
file:///Users/.../Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_cupertino_localizations-1.0.1/lib/src/cupertino_localizations.dart:127:38: Error: Getter not found: 'kSupportedLanguages'.
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => kSupportedLanguages.contains(locale.languageCode);
```

This used to compile fine the last time I worked on this project (a few weeks back). The only thing I can think off that has changed is the Xcode version I am using (was version 10, is now version 11).

The output of `flutter --version` is:

Flutter 1.5.8 • channel unknown • unknown source
Framework • revision 0ba67226ee (6 months ago) • 2019-04-24 17:18:28 -0700
Engine • revision c63d1cf9c9
Tools • Dart 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.1 1f1592edce)

Comment: It might be the error of package, some packages doesn't get released for the updated flutter or Xcode, hence you get the error. Research more, and if that is the case, you have to look for some other package like this which is compatible for this updated version of the flutter.

Answer (score 2):

That erros probably is show because you config locales in your `MaterialApp` like this:

```
  MaterialApp(
  ...
    localizationsDelegates: [
      GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    ],
    supportedLocales: [const Locale('pt', 'BR')],
  );
```

but you forgot of add `GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate` in you `localizationsDelegates`. Then to fix this problem just add it like this:

```
  MaterialApp(
  ...
    localizationsDelegates: [
      GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
    ],
    supportedLocales: [const Locale('pt', 'BR')],
  );
```

but if you remove all this configurations, you app will load configuration default and will works perfectly. But the language default is English.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `flutter_cupertino_localizations` anymore for the latest `flutter_localizations`. See the latest [flutter_localizations documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations-library.html), it contains cupertino localizations methods. The [flutter website for internationalization](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) is currently (as of 7th Jan 2020) is out of date and needs to be changed to not tell people we need to use `flutter_cupertino_localizations` package.